# I would like to find goes up by one and falls by one. Use SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

I think about that problem for one week.

Anyway.I would like to find goes up by one and falls by one. Use SQL.

For example

This table exists.

```
name: ValTable



No  val  
1  → 2  
2  → 3  
3  → 2  
4  → 4  
5  → 3  
6  → 3  
7  → 4  
8  → 3  
9  → 2  
10 → 0
```

Two points are applied.

```
① No.1-3 → 2,3(+1),2(-1)  
② No.6-8 → 3,4(+1),3(-1)
```

Is carrying out using a SQL possible?
`(Oracle, Posgresql, MySQL`)
It is enough if the very first number is known.

OR Please advice should I change table structure and good

Comment: Please edit your question and show your desired results.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.val first, t2.val second, t3.val third
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t2.no = t1.no + 1 AND t2.val = t1.val + 1
JOIN test t3 ON t3.no = t2.no + 1 AND t3.val = t1.val
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02685/7

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was able to get the values！

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres and Oracle, you can use the `lead()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(val) over (order by no) as val1, lead(val, 2) over (order by no) as val2
      from table t
     ) t
where val1 = val + 1 and val2 + val;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support this ANSI standard functionality, although you could mimic it with joins.

Comment: thank you!!I think it tries to one million records, Is it going to be fast How do I?

Comment: @Shinya . . . I would expected the window/analytic functions to be faster than joins.  However, you should test them in your environment to determine if that is true.

Comment: Thank you! I use the AWS, I will try and use it.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, You can get

```
SELECT t1.val VAL1, t2.val VAL2, t3.val VAL3
FROM valTable v1, valTable v2, valTable v3
WHERE V1.NO = (V2.NO + 1)
AND   V1.VAL = (V2.VAL + 1)
AND   V2.NO = (V3.NO + 1)
AND   V2.VAL = (V3.VAL + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for writing the answer!!I was helpful to

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do with analytic functions.  LEAD and LAG allow us to work with values from the next and previous rows in the result set.

Like this (in Oracle):

```
with vals as (
    select id as curr_id
           , lag(id) over (order by id) prev_id
           , lead(id) over (order by id) next_id
           , val as curr_val
           , lag(val) over (order by id) prev_val
           , lead(val) over (order by id) next_val
    from valtable
   )
   , diffs as (
   select prev_id 
          , next_id
          , prev_val
          , curr_val
          , next_val
          , ( curr_val - prev_val ) as prev_diff
          , ( next_val - curr_val ) as next_diff
  from vals )
select 
       *
from diffs
where prev_diff = 1
and next_diff = -1
;
```

As a bonus the SQL Fiddle includes the required formatting of the output.  [Check it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecccb/7).

Comment: Wow!!  Output format until it's the same!  I appreciate. Respect!